# comparação de floats

Tags: c

Este programa permite verificar qual dos três floats é o maior, só que está a  ignorar as casas decimais.

Por exemplo se eu colocar os valores `1.4`, `1.6` e `1.5`, o programa diz me que o maior é o valor `1.4`. Como resolvo o problema??

```
void main()
{ 
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese"); 
  double numero1,numero2,numero3; 
  printf(" introduza o 1º numero, 2º numero e 3º numero!\n"); 
  scanf("%f %f %f", &numero1, &numero2, &numero3); 
  if (numero1 > numero2 && numero1 > numero3) 
  printf(" O 1º número introduzido é o maior!\n");
  else if (numero2 > numero1 && numero2 > numero3) 
  printf(" O 2º número é o mairo!\n"); 
  else printf(" O 3º numero é o maior!\n"); 
}
```

Comment: Verifica se o `scanf` está a ir buscar os números como deve ser com um `printf`. Está?

Comment: A cultura que você configurou (portuguese) usa virgula como casa decimal. Use uma cultura com ponto para casas decimais, ou use , quando for digitar os números.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
  double numero1, numero2, numero3;
  scanf("%f %f %f", &numero1, &numero2, &numero3);
```

Erro: a especificação `"%f"` do `scanf()` espera um ponteiro para uma variavél do tipo `float`, mas estás a passar um ponteiro para variável de tipo `double`.

Ou mudas o tipo das variáves (não aconselho, usa sempre `double`) ou mudas a especificação no `scanf()` e verifica se correu tudo bem

```
  if (scanf("%lf%lf%lf", &numero1, &numero2, &numero3) != 3) /* erro */;
```

Comment: obrigado funciona :)

Comment: @pmg, a sua resposta funcionou. Não sei se a minha está correta, mas se achar que sim, incorpore na sua para que eu posso delatar a minha.

Comment: @pmg a ideia era ele chegar lá sozinho ;) +1